# Parse string with regular expression using JavaScript

Tags: regex

Need help with regular expression in JavaScript

I have a semicolon delimited string of hyperlinks:

```
 "<a onclick="RemoveValue('Asthma', '1')">Asthma</a>; <a onclick="RemoveValue('Alzheimer’s Disease', '2')"> Alzheimer’s Disease</a>; <a onclick="RemoveValue('Depression', '3')">Depression</a>"
```

I need to remove below part of the string using regular expression:

```js
“<a onclick="RemoveValue('Alzheimer’s Disease', '2')"> Alzheimer’s Disease</a>”
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have no clue to why or what you're trying to accomplish the regex may not work. Next time, please give us some context. It helps us and you. The other thing is try to show what you've tried yourself so we don't just repeat the same suggestion you've already tried.

Anyway here's a simple regex that will do this, but technically you could just do a `replace` to remove the occurrences of the string you provided.

```
<a[^>]+onclick="RemoveValue\('Alzheimer’s Disease'[^"]+">[^<]+</a>(?:;\s)?
```

[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kA0qP9/1)

For the JS side it should look something similar to this:

```
var str = "<a onclick=\"RemoveValue('Asthma', '1')\">Asthma</a>; <a onclick=\"RemoveValue('Alzheimer’s Disease', '2')\"> Alzheimer’s Disease</a>; <a onclick=\"RemoveValue('Depression', '3')\">Depression</a>";

var re = /<a[^>]+onclick="RemoveValue\('Alzheimer’s Disease'[^"]+">[^<]+<\/a>(?:;\s)?/gi;
var reOutput = str.replace(re, "");
console.log(reOutput);
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dah9f6km/) - Check console window.